# How can i remove json object from mysql sequalize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using Nodejs express and my database is Mysql with sequalize.. I am storing very large json data but my requirement is i want to clear stored json first, then store new json that is coming from req.body.

How can i do it..

To insert data i am using set method... but in any way i try to remove it first. it takes a lot of time and crashes the server.

`

I am trying this way but it crashes the server

```
`const updateQuery = `UPDATE Users SET files = '[]' WHERE id = :userId`;
await sequelize.query(updateQuery, {
replacements: { userId },
type: sequelize.QueryTypes.UPDATE,
});


User.set("files", [
...User.files,
{
fileName: file.originalname,
fileData: newjson,
uploadTime: new Date(),
},
]);
 await User.save();`
```

Comment: What query crashes the server? I suspect the `set` or `save`. And why couldn't you use one `user.updateById` instead of two queries? There is no need to clear a field first, simply overwrite its content by `update`

Comment: my jsons data are very big, the crash is generally shows something as timout..

Comment: I'd recommend to store files outside DB in some cloud storage like S3 or Google and only store a link to a file in DB if files are really big. Anyway it's not good to store several big objects in one JSON field (maybe it's better at least to create a separate table for files)